# to transcribe a string calling it with the name of another string, is it possible? in c# on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a string variable called "A" and the internal string is "a000_1" (the numbers of this string can change.)
then I have other strings called: "a000_1", "a000_2", "a000_3" etc ... (with each a different text inside)
I have to transcribe the variables a001 etc. calling them automatically with the string "A"

so if the text inside the string "A" is, for example, "a000_7" it must transcribe the text inside the variable "a000_7"

```
ExampleText.SetText(A)
```

but obviously if I do that
transcribes me "a000_7", if we want to go back to the example above,
and not the text inside the variable a000_7

Comment: *transcribe* generally means to put speech or spoken words into written form.  That seems to be the wrong word here.  `A` is basically a handle to the text "a000_7" or whatever else.  You can easily change what text it represents and/or change the text itself.   It does seem you are making things more complicated

Comment: variable A is generated by other algorithms and the texts that I have to transcribe are many I cannot do it manually (with if for example):
if (A == "a000_7") {
text.SetText (a007_7)
}
if (A == "a000_8") {
text.SetText (a000_8)
}
in this way I would have to write hundreds instead I think it can be done automatically, I hope. (maybe I didn't explain myself well at the beginning)

Comment: How do you create a007_7, a007_8 variables in first place? If you can use them as string keys to a dictionary you can handle that problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a dictionary here:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    ["a000_1"] = "test1",
    ["a000_2"] = "test2",
    ["a000_3"] = "test3",
    ["a000_4"] = "test4",
    ["a000_5"] = "test5",
    ["a000_6"] = "test6",
    ["a000_7"] = "test7",
};
String A = "a000_7";
Console.WriteLine(dict[A]);
```

In this case, you can access one of the strings by name by using A as the key to the dict